# Is it possible to use Enzyme's snapshots on React fragments?

Tags: reactjs, testing, enzyme

I'm wondering if React fragments are compatible with Enzyme's snapshots. Right now it seems like fragments from React 16+ are being rendered as Symbols in enzyme's `shallow()` method, which is causes a conversion error:`"TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string"`.

Here's my test:

```
it('should render successfully', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(
    <Sections
      data={mappedMockData}
      sections={mappedMockData.sections}
      eligibility={mockEligibility}
    />
);

console.log(wrapper.debug());

expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
```

And here's the output from my console.log:

```
  <Symbol(react.fragment)>
    <div className="content-container">
      <div className="flex">
        <div className="sections-wrap">
          <Connect(Section1) />
          <Connect(Section2) />
        </div>
        <Connect(Section3) />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="content-container">
      <Connect(Section4) />
      <Connect(Section5) />
    </div>
  </Symbol(react.fragment)>
```

Worth noting: I've already updated my Enzyme and React, and am already using an adapter, as suggested by enzyme's [migration guide](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/guides/migration-from-2-to-3.md). I haven't been able to find other similar issues to this on stack overflow or Github. Thanks in advance for any insights!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [enzyme issue comment](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1213#issuecomment-339103821) was helpful for a valid test.  (The whole thread is useful for knowing more about the status of fragments with enzyme snapshot testing.)  But this code worked for me, and outputs `<Unknown></Unknown>` in the snapshot's template literal in the place of `<React.Fragment>`:

```
const component = shallow(<FragmentComponent />)
const fragment = component.instance().render()
expect(shallow(<div>{fragment}</div>).getElement()).toMatchSnapshot()
```

Here is sample output:

```
exports[`<FragmentComponent /> it renders to match the snapshot 1`] = `
<div>
  <Unknown>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </Unknown>
</div>
`;
```

**UPDATE (JULY 2018):**

Jest Version 23.0.0 (https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2300) added support for rendering `<React.Fragment>` in snapshots with https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/5816/files#diff-d7b82d8b858fb8e0b01a91859362b75a.

Comment: Thanks! This work, I just wish that there was a cleaner solution for such a (seemingly) easy problem :/